# NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key must be present in Info.plist to use camera roll

Tags: ios, react-native, info.plist

Recently I started to get this error:

> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key must be present in Info.plist to
>   use camera roll.

I am using React Native to build my app (I am not familiar with ios native development) and I don't know how to add this key to Info.plist

Can you post an example? Thanks

I am using npm package `"react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.1.7"`

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476283/1226963 for an example of what to add to Info.plist. Also, just do a search on `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 548, accepted):

Thanks @rmaddy, I added this just after other key-string pairs in Info.plist and fixed the problem:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

**Edit:**

I also ended up having similar problems on different components of my app. Ended up adding all these keys so far (after updating to Xcode8/iOS10):

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Checkout this [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) link for **full list** of property list key references.

**Full List:**

Apple Music:

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Bluetooth:

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>  
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Calendar:

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Camera:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Contacts:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

FaceID:

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Health Share:

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Health Update:

```
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Home Kit:

```
<key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location:

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location (Always):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location (When in use):

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Microphone:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Motion (Accelerometer):

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

NFC (Near-field communication):

```
<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Photo Library:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Photo Library (Write-only access):

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Reminders:

```
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Siri:

```
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Speech Recognition:

```
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Comment: I have been using the string, "This app does not require access to the photo library."

Comment: I have added key and string in info.plist file then i build app using terminal and all these changes has been removed. please guide on it

Comment: I added this but it still crashing with same error. Why this is happening?

Comment: where to find info.plist file in ionic ? I am not able to get that.

Answer (score 85):

MY FAVORITE WAY TO DO IT

**1. Open `info.plist`**

[image]

**2. Click this button to add a new key**

[image]

**3. Scroll down to find** *Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description*

[image]

**4. Select it, then add your description on the right**

[image]

Comment: I added this but it still crashing with same error. Why this is happening?

Comment: @fish40 maybe you can try clicking project-target-info, and add it there and see what happens?

Comment: your key description made my day XD

Comment: Usage description tickled me. Fixed my issue too so happy bonus!

Comment: where to find info.plist file ? I am not able to get that.

Comment: @Anuj if you can't find it, you might've deleted it. You can create a new one by File -> New -> File

Comment: @Anuj check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) where to find info.plist

Answer (score 21):

As of now August 2021,
not only we have to add this :

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key> 
<string>We need access to photo library so that photos can be selected</string>
```

but also need to add this to info.plist file inside iOS folder in order to work properly

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>    
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

Answer (score 18):

Add following code in info.plist file

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed... with the source way I finally succeeded in uploading my app! TNX :)

Comment: It's strange that this worked, but the other approaches didn't, maybe it's just a bug on xcode 9 beta. Many thanks for this!!!

Comment: Welcome, Happy it's help to you.

Answer (score 16):

You need to paste these two in your info.plist, The only way that worked in iOS 11 for me.

```
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

Comment: The latter is only required if you are requesting permission to add to the photo library. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription)

Answer (score 5):

For camera access use:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera Access Warning</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

i faced the same issue few days earlier for my IONIC 4 Project. when i uploaded my IPA, i got this warnings from App Store Connect.

[image]

I fixed the "Missing  Purpose String in info.plist" issue, by the following steps. hope it will also work for you.

1. Goto your "info.plist" file.

[image]

2. Find this key, called `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`. if it's not present there, add a new one and it's value, like below image.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using `NSCameraUsageDescription` the user can access the camera AND select images from the photo library. So I don’t need `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save or retrieve an image from the camera roll. Additionally, you need to ask the user for the permission otherwise you'll get this error or your app may get crashed. To save yourself from this add this into your info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires read and write permission from the user.</string>
```

In the case of Xamarin.iOS

```
 if you're adding it from the generic editor then "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" will be the given option you will find out instead of "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription".
```

Answer (score 1):

If you added the key-string pairs in Info.plist ([see Murat's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/10739241) ) and still getting the error, try to check if the target you're currently working on has the keys.

In my case I had 2 targets (dev and development). I added the keys in the editor, but it only works for the main target and I was testing on development target. So I had to open XCode, click on the project > Info > Add the key-pair for the development target there.

Comment: This was my case too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

```
"Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" for iOS 11 and later

"Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" for iOS 6.0 and later
```

Open plist file and this code

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error while uploading my flutter app to app store connect. STEPS I EMPLOYED TO FIX IT:

1. Opened the ios folder of my flutter project in XCode
2. Inside the runner folder, I clicked on info.split file
3. clicked + button in front of "information property list"
4. I scroll down until I find "privacy - Photo Library Usage Description". I clicked on that.
5. Then input a description message of why you seek the photo permission in the string section. In my case, the string I supplied was -> "This app need permission to access camera and photo library".