# Missing Info.plist key Unable to resolve

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I have been getting an error for days as I mentioned below. And in no way did I find a solution.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Application Name". To process your delivery, the following issues
>   must be corrected:
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I want to add in the info.plist file. How do I make a change? I'm glad you helped me.

My info.plist

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
 <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
 <string>OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
 <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>XPC!</string>
 <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>2.4</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>2.4.4</string>
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
 <string>We, however, intend to record the members' profile pictures and not to take photographs of the products they will use in their orders.</string>
 <key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>NotificationService</string>
 </dict>
 <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
 <string>However, we aim to record the members' profile pictures and to select photographs of the products they use in their orders.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/5167909

Comment: Hey @FaysalAhmed I made a correction. I did what you were told in the dirt. But again I did not get a result