# UIImagePickerController not asking for permission

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, info.plist

I have implemented the following code in an app to allow the user to add an image to the app. However the user is never asked for permission to access photo's. What am I missing here?

in my info.plist I have set:
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description = Please provide access to your photo library

The bundle identifier is:
$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

```
import UIKit

class NewPostXIB: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func addImageButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does the picker appear?

Comment: delete the app from phone and try again.

Comment: The picker appears and allows me to choose an image. I have deleted the app, and reset privacy settings - still doesn't ask for permission

Comment: Also add this : Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description

Comment: I solved this problem. my issues are xCode location. xCode location is Desktop that time permission popup not coming, move to the application folder after restart my computer and worked well.

Comment: I tried both of those. I have other projects stored on the desktop and they ask for permission.

Comment: Wish I could answer this - Apple's way of keeping us on our toes? Anyways, if you are using iOS 10, there's a different key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519773/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-key-must-be-present-in-info-plist-to-use-camera-r If this is the issue, let me know - I'll try to mark this as duplicate (it will helps others and isn't a rep hit for you).

Comment: I'm using iOS11. It's so frustrating! It works how I want it but doesn't ask for permission so I know that would be rejected if I submit to the App store.
Even if I take my photo library entries out of the info.plist. uninstall the app, reinstall and run, access to the photo library is granted with no crash or problems. I thought the app would crash if no entries are in the info.plist - Or so I read on the Apple dev website!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the following function solved the problem:

```
 func checkPermission() {
    let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Access is granted by user")
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
            (newStatus) in
            print("status is \(newStatus)")
            if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                /* do stuff here */
                self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("success")
            }
        })
        print("It is not determined until now")
    case .restricted:
        // same same
        print("User do not have access to photo album.")
    case .denied:
        // same same
        print("User has denied the permission.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for solution. only thing missing is PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization is done in background thread. so the line for showing picker should be brought to main thread with like "DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }"

Answer (score 28):

The answer is simple: it's normal behavior since iOS 11, because the `UIImagePickerController` runs in a separate process and therefore for just read-only access you don't need any special permissions.

Comment: this is what I want, it saves me from documentation read, thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

According to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/requesting_authorization_to_access_photos)

> Note
>
> When using the UIImagePickerController to bring up the user's photo
> library, your app doesn't need to request permission explicitly.

Photos automatically prompts the user to request authorization when needed.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Although I am able to display the picker without asking permission, I then want to get PHAssetResource.assetResources on the selected image, which fails without permission, so scottc00's answer helps in my case