# Can't upload an iOS app into app store and Can't choose my .ipa file in app store

Tags: ios, xcode

I have already uploaded my app to the iOS app store. Now I need to release an updated version. For that, I create a "version or platform" in app store. But in there, I can't upload or select my updated version of .ipa file. This means it does not show any icon or file to upload or select my updated version file. It simply shows "Submit your builds using Xcode or Application Loader. See supported versions
".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFKSe.png)

Comment: what happens when you upload the new version build from Xcode or Application Loader?

Comment: You can only upload IPA file by `Xcode` or `Application loader`.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr In Xcode if I click "Upload to app store" it gets uploading and also in iTunes login in "Activity" -> "All builds" -> it showing "Processing" and after that it get disappeared and also not available in "Build" section. Build section shows like previously I attached image.

Comment: @Rocky uploading field is not enabled....

Comment: Should we change the Build and Version number when we updating a existing app in app store or should we change version only? or should we change build only?

Comment: You need to update build number each time when uploading with same version.

Comment: Same version is "Ready for Sale" in app store. what should I do?

Comment: `Ready for Sale` mean your app is now available on iTunes Store.

Comment: The version of the build you upload must match the new version in App Store Connect for that build to appear in the screen you are looking at.

Comment: My app version in "Ready for Sale" is 1.2 and Build is 1. So if I need to update my app means should I change my version or build or both?

Comment: And after all that my issue is what I meant at top. Kindly guide me to get out of this struggle. I got into this 7 days ago.

Comment: When you create a new "Version or platform" you select iOS and enter a version number that is higher than 1.2 (1.3 or 1.5 or 2.3 etc).  You must enter this version into your project in Xcode before you archive it.  Then, after you upload it and it finishes processing you will see it as an available build in App Store Connect for the new version

Comment: For a new version you should update the version number to a higher number than on in `Ready for Sale`. If the build is disappearing after processing means your build has some errors/compatibility issue with store guidelines (may be build SDK version or it can be anything). Apple will notify the issue through an email to the logged in Apple Dev Account. If the email is belong to you, have a look or if the email account belongs to some one else, ask them to check for an email from AppStoreConnect.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Awesome awesome............ I really expect this one.........My issue solved.........

Comment: Refer this link dudes..........
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519773/nsphotolibraryusagedescription-key-must-be-present-in-info-plist-to-use-camera-r

Comment: @RanjithKumar i'm adding the comment as answer so that you can accept and mark the question as answered. Otherwise this will still list in unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new version, you should update the version number to a higher number than on in `Ready for Sale`. If the build is disappearing after processing means your build has some **errors/compatibility issue** with store guidelines (may be build SDK version or it can be anything). Apple will notify the issue through an email to the logged in Apple Dev Account. If the email is belong to you, have a look or if the email account belongs to some one else, ask them to check for an email from `AppStoreConnect`