# How to add camera permissions into flutter project?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-camera, ios-permissions

I want to open the camera by clicking a button but cannot add the **camera** and **gallery** permissions in the **iOS** package.

I have those keys:

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSCameraUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
```

And I don't know where I should put those lines.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 18):

**edit this file:**

```
[Flutter Project Folder]/ios/Runner/Info.plist
```

**add these entries:**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>App needs access to photo lib for profile images</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>
```

the string part can be any description you want the user to see as an explanation for why your app needs these privileges

these lines should be added after the  tag

there is a good elaboration for other options here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/530884

Answer (score 2):

To add permissions in Flutter, you must add permissions to both the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the `info.plist` file.

To add the specific permissions you are asking to the info.plist, you can go to:

> iOS -> Runner -> info.plist

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example project for the `camera` package: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/camera/example/ios/Runner/Info.plist

You'll see that those lines are in with the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

you should try by updating the podfile

[You can follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608443/flutter-ios-can-not-use-microphone-problem-with-permission-handler)

By this you can set the permission by default and on the permission dialog, it'll update the permission

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34927616)

Comment: @Yaroslavm thanks for the clarification

you can add the permissions directly in the podfile
Example: 

`post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|

      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1'
      ]

    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add permission in ios/Runner/info.plist

   ```
   <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
   <string>This app needs image library access to select invoice images</string>
   ```

> ```
> <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> <string>This app requires camera access for QR scans and invoice uploads</string>
> ```

2. Change ios/Podfile

> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>             config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
>                '$(inherited)',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
>                ##'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
>                #'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
>                # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
>                'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
>                #'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
>                #'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0'
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
>                'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
>
>                ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
>                ##'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
>                ##'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
>                 ##'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
>                 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
>
>                ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
>                #'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
>              ]
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

3. Delete Podfile.lock
4. Delete pubspec.lock
5. Clean everything

> ```
> pod cache clean —all
> flutter clean
> flutter pub get
> (cd ios && pod install)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Permissions for gallery, camera, and microphone (etc) should be added to the `ios/Runner/info.plist` file, just before the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key.

```
<dict>
    <!-- permissions -->
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please grant photo gallery access</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please grant camera access</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please grant microphone access</string>
    <!-- end permissions -->
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
</dict>
```

> Note that a plist file is tab-delimited, so you should not use spaces.