# How to declare camera and gallery permission in flutter for iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I use image picker and gallery saver in my project. But I don't know how to give permission for iOS I know how add permission in Android but I can't understand where I put permission and what permission I want for camera and gallery. I completed Android permission but I don't know how I put permission on iOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add camera permissions into flutter project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374824/how-to-add-camera-permissions-into-flutter-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Info.plist file in the ios/Runner folder of your Flutter project.

> Add the following keys to the Info.plist file:

```
<dict>
    <!-- Other keys and configurations... -->
    
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your app needs access to the camera to take photos and videos.</string>
    
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your app needs access to the photo library to select photos and videos.</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the edit the `Info.plist` file in your XCode project [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970037/12731963) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610075/12731963)