# Flutter app with agora video call crashing on testflight

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight, agora.io

I have implemented Agora video call in my flutter app. I have put it on testflight also.
Video call is working when I run it in debug and also in android. It is working on ios simulators also. But when I open the app with testflight and go on the video call app, the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face it many times :) It's a high chance because you didn't declare permission asking in `info.plist`. Ex:

```xml
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519960/19992458

> Note: Come back if this doesn't resolve your problem.